# Preprocessing twig templates

Tags: theming, 9

I currently have two templates, one of which is *page.html.twig*, which is the main page and I can preprocess with `MYTHEME_preprocess_page()`. `MYTHEME_preprocess_page()` affects all the other pages in different modules.

The other template is *_carousel.html.twig* (theme/templates/includes/_carousel), which I include into *page.html.twig*, but I cannot hook into it with `MYTHEME_preprocess__carousel()`.

Is this the default behavior, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, preprocess_page affects all pages, because that is the rendering stack. HTML, Page, Region, blocks, etc. Its hard to tell what you are trying to do here without more information.

Comment: @Kevin I guess the question is why `MYTHEME_preprocess__carousel()` cannot be used for a template file that is included into another template file.

Comment: Hey @Kevin, sorry for not answering earlier. What i'm trying to do is more of a reusable component approach. Since i need the same carousel on another page, I want to fetch the data only when it's included, not on every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hook_preprocess_page()` is invoked for every page Drupal renders. That's why it needs to check for which page is invoked, if it really needs to preprocess specific pages.
A preprocess hook isn't invoked for template files that are included from other template files.

For both the cases, the answer is yes, that is default, expected behavior.